# Block Ip list / country using IIS/Coldfusion

Tags: iis, coldfusion, spam, application.cfc

I am getting a lot of spam/unwanted traffic from ips from China for eg. 125.116.123.14 as seen in my FTP logs with attempts log in etc.

Is there a way i can block this in Coldfusion Application.cfc? Currently i am manually going and blocking them on IIS.

Comment: ColdFusion doesn't run your FTP server - it wont have any effect on blocking those. Talk to your hosting provider or network department about setting up IP whitelisting/blacklisting.  (Also, you could consider changing it to a non-standard port, and closing the default.)

Comment: @PeterBoughton Personally I thought that mentioned FTP log is just one of the sources of collecting the IP addresses. If not, you're definitely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as this in the top of Application.cfc:

```
<cfif Left(cgi.REMOTE_ADDR, 7) EQ "125.116">
    <cfabort/>
</cfif>
```

You can play with checking patterns and achieve some acceptable results.

But still, *I would recommend to handle it at web-server level for better efficiency*. I don't know much about advanced IIS stuff, but extensions like [Dynamic IP Restictions](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions) may work for you.

Comment: Oooh, Dynamic IP Restrictions seem awesome :)